# C# avoid repeating code for interface property

Tags: c#, class, interface, repeat

Given the interface:

```
interface IVotable
{
    int TotalUpvotes { get; }
    int TotalDownvotes { get; }
    int TotalVoteScore { get; }
}
```

With an implementation:

```
public class Comment : IVotable
{
    public int TotalUpvotes { get; private set; }
    public int TotalDownvotes { get; private set; }
    public int TotalVoteScore { get { return TotalUpvotes - TotalDownvotes + 1 ; } }
}
```

What's the best way to avoid implementing `TotalVoteScore` the same way in each class?

Comment: What about inheritance rather than an interface? Make all the classes inherit from a class with those properties.

Comment: make ivotable as abstract, make totalvotescore as a virtual method. ?

Comment: abstract class is what you're after

Comment: If `TotalVoteScore` is always calculated the same way you can just make it an extension method on `IVotable`.

Comment: @BarryOKane, that's what I had it as before.  However my understanding is that it's best to use inheritance when every child class always has the properties, and interfaces when the child classes might have the properties.

Most child classes in my cases wont implement IVotable

Comment: @TomGullen No, that's not the difference between inheritance and interfaces.  Inheritance determines _implementation_, interfaces just determine the _contract_ (methods, properties, etc).  If you want to dictate a specific implementation then you need to use inheritance.  You can't define an interface in a way that forces a specific implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `TotalVoteScore` is always calculated the same way you can just make it an extension method on `IVotable`:

```
public static int TotalVoteScore(this IVotable v) {
    return v.TotalUpvotes - v.TotalDownvotes + 1
}
```

Comment: With the added bonus that `int TotalVoteScore()` can be "overridden" by an actual implementation. Because extension methods have a lower priority.

Comment: I don't like using extensions for interfaces and classes that i'm currently planning. How do i implement a different behaviour, with another magic extension like `TotalVoteScoreSchemaXY`?

Comment: @Corak - An instance method will only be chosen if the receiver is a concrete type implementing `IVotable`. If all your have is an `IVotable` instance then the extension method must be chosen even if the implmenting type has a `TotalVoteScore` method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - If you need different behaviour then obviously you need to move the method to the interface. There's no reason to do that until you actually require different behaviours.

Comment: @Lee - ah, you're right. So this is only if one is *sure* that the calculation is always the same.

Comment: This breaks the `IVotable` interface by requiring that it removes the `TotalVoteScore` property. It then means only the code that happens to reference the code with the extension method will see `TotalVoteScore`. This is terrible.

Comment: @Enigmativity - If there is only one way to calculate `TotalVoteScore` then it doesn't need to be on `IVotable` at all. This is far preferable to having each implementation copy and paste the same function. Any client that needs the functionality obviously needs to bring it into scope.

Comment: @Lee - An interface is a code contract. This breaks the contract. In fact, it even allows rogue code to come in and implement its own extension method which can the destabilize the entire code base. No, this is a terrible solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Your objection only applies if this interface is some public artefact with existing external implementations, and there isn't enough information in the question to tell. In that case you could call this method something else to avoid confusion. If this is a new interface then there is no existing contract to break.

Comment: @Lee  While your solution does prevent code duplication, you move implementation details away from where they belong: in the class itself. IMO a better solution is to have a virtual method in an abstract base class and inherit from that (as well as the interface).

Comment: @WicherVisser - If the behaviour is the same across all implementations then it doesn't belong in the implementing classes, but should be associated with the interface. This is the closest you can get to that in C# in the absence of traits. Putting it in a base class forces all implementors to either inherit the base class or copy the implementation, neither of which are desirable.

Comment: @Lee - The interface is the contract, regardless how new it is. The instant an interface is made, whether it is public or private, it is a contract. Your solution changes the interface so thus changes the contract. There's no two ways about this.

Comment: Leave the interface as is. Comment class would call the extension method which contains the business logic as such "public int TotalVoteScore { get { return this.TotalVoteScore() } }". Constrain the class containing the extension method to internal if there's value to that. Implementation details remain in the class as far as I'm concerned, no contracts broken. Code reused.

Comment: @Enigmativity - You can change the contract if all sides agree and that is trivially the case when there are no implementations.

Comment: @TrevorAsh - That approach still requires you to duplicate the definition of `TotalVoteScore` in every implementing class.

Comment: @Lee - You can turn around and write the code in assembler if everyone agrees, but that doesn't change the fact that the contract has changed. It might be trivial when there are no implementations, but you can accrue some serious technical debt. This is still a bad solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity - There is no 'technical debt' if all sides agree to the new contract. This is the best approach for new interfaces, and if you are in a position to change any existing one. Copy/pasting the definition or enforcing the use of a superclass is much worse than defining the behaviour in a single function. Those are only preferable if there is a risk of breaking existing implementations.

Comment: @Lee - I disagree with "There is no 'technical debt' if all sides agree to the new contract" - you get technical debt from bad design. If a bunch of people make a bad decision then you have technical debt, regardless of how much they agreed.

Answer (score 6):

If it is only `TotalVoteScore` that you don't want to have to re-implement, then this is the way to go:

```
public interface IVotable
{
    int TotalUpvotes { get; }
    int TotalDownvotes { get; }
    int TotalVoteScore { get; }
}

public abstract class VotableBase : IVotable
{
    public abstract int TotalUpvotes { get; protected set; }
    public abstract int TotalDownvotes { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int TotalVoteScore { get { return TotalUpvotes - TotalDownvotes + 1 ; } }
}

public class Comment : VotableBase
{
    public override int TotalUpvotes { get; protected set; }
    public override int TotalDownvotes { get; protected set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want something like an interface (a contract that says that there have to be some methods with a specified signature) combined with common code, I guess the solution is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Votable
{
    public abstract int TotalUpvotes { get; protected set; }
    public abstract int TotalDownvotes { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int TotalVoteScore { get { return TotalUpvotes - TotalDownvotes + 1; } }
}
```

and derive from that class:

```
public class Comment : Votable
{
    public override int TotalUpvotes { get; protected set; }
    public override int TotalDownvotes { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? `'Comment' does not implement inherited abstract member 'VotableBase.TotalUpvotes.get'` & `'Comment' does not implement inherited abstract member 'VotableBase.TotalDownvotes.get'`.

Comment: Now you have `Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Votable' is less accessible than class 'Comment'`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok, ok, I just wanted to show the idea and copied the code from OP. I'll add that little `public` keyword for completeness :)

Comment: Now you have `'Comment.TotalUpvotes.set': cannot override because 'Votable.TotalUpvotes' does not have an overridable set accessor`. You really should test before posting.

Comment: @RenéVogt if you don't know about it yet, https://dotnetfiddle.net/ is a great place to quickly check to see if some piece of code compiles/works online.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class VotableBase
{
    public int TotalUpvotes { get; protected set;}
    public int TotalDownvotes { get; protected set; }
    public int TotalVoteScore { get { return TotalUpvotes - TotalDownvotes + 1 ; } }
}
```

then your derived class doesn't need any implementation for this - it already inherits the properties:

```
public class Comment : VotableBase
{
    public void DoThings()
    {
        //e.g.
        Console.WriteLine(TotalVoteScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: If everything is declared in the base class, why is it `abstract`? It doesn't have any absract members.

Comment: nothing requires an abstract class to have abstract members.  It just defines a base class that cannot stand alone as a complete object.  Certainly he can modify to meet his needs, this is to serve as an example.

Comment: Strictly speaking the other two should be virtual in case some classes need to change the behavior in the `get` or `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing the composition approach into the mix. I'm not against inheritance at all. But this strikes me as a good case to NOT use it. Why constrain this class from only being able to derive voting capabilities? I can imagine this class having a lot of things more closely related to a "Comment" such as author information (ranking, bio, avatar), formatting, age, edit history, etc. Some of which seem potentially more suited as a base class.

```
public interface IVotable
{
    int TotalUpvotes { get; }
    int TotalDownvotes { get; }
    int TotalVoteScore { get; }
}

// shared implementation
public class VoteStatus : IVotable
{
    public int TotalUpvotes { get; private set; }
    public int TotalDownvotes { get; private set; }
    public int TotalVoteScore { get { return TotalUpvotes - TotalDownvotes + 1; } }
}

// has A...
public class Comment : IVotable
{
    // expose it?
    public IVotable VoteStatus { get; private set; }

    // allow current vote status to be injected?
    public Comment(IVotable voteStatusReference)
    {
        this.VoteStatus = voteStatusReference;
    }

    // or don't use injection?
    public Comment()
        : this(new VoteStatus())
    {
    }

    public int TotalUpvotes => this.VoteStatus.TotalUpvotes;
    public int TotalDownvotes => this.VoteStatus.TotalDownvotes;
    public int TotalVoteScore => this.VoteStatus.TotalVoteScore;
}
```

Note: I felt the extension method suggestion was better than inheritance here as well.